# sql: count cases (weighted)

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, sum

I have the following SQL-Table with an id an id2, a group-variable (grp), a variable `var` (a or b) and a counting variable.

```
id | id2 | grp | var | count
---------------------------------
1    1     1     a     1    
2    1     1     b     1 
3    2     1     a     2
4    3     1     a     2
5    4     1     b     2
6    5     2     a     1
7    6     2     a     1
8    7     2     a     2
9    8     2     b     2
```

Now, my goal is to get rid of all the duplicates of variable `id2`. Then I would like to get the **number of cases per group** WHERE var='a' AND **the cases having a count value > 1 should be counted multiple times** (according to the value of "count").

What I have already is this:

```
SELECT 
 DISTINCT id2,
 SUM(*) AS count, 
 grp AS group 
FROM table
WHERE var='a'
GROUP BY grp;
```

I thought, maybe I could use the SUM-function somehow, but I didnt manage to get it to work.

The result should be like:

```
grp | var | count | id2
------------------------
1     a     5       ..
2     a     4       ..
```

Comment: Expected output will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUM` is the correct approach but you need to fix the syntax:

```
SELECT grp, var, SUM(count) AS `count`
FROM t
WHERE var = 'a'
GROUP BY grp, var
```

Comment: Thank you very much! However, I first also have to drop the duplicates of id2. That's why I was trying `SELECT DISTINCT id2`...

Comment: Your expected output does not contain id2. Am I missing something?

Comment: I am actually not interested in the value of id2 in the output. I just dont know how I can drop the duplicates without using `SELECT DISTINCT id2`

Comment: Does noeone else have an idea? I still can't include the DISTINCT in my query in order to sort the duplicates of id2 out. Maybe with a subquery?